# Any way to terminate a Java thread in a 3rd party library?

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc

I'm using a JDBC driver for database access. Sometimes, due to what appears to be a bug in the JDBC driver, database calls hang and don't return a result.

I'm working around this problem by detecting the hang and re-running the query on a new thread. This works. However, the old thread doesn't go away; it continues to hang until the JVM is exited. I'd like to clean up these threads instead of leaving them stuck forever. Interrupting the JDBC access thread has no effect.

Is this a case for calling Thread.stop()? If not, is there anything else that can be done to terminate the thread?

I can't fix the root problem, because I don't have the source code for the JDBC driver and the vendor is not interested in fixing it.

Comment: You can use [Thread.interrupt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt()) instead. Make sure to also read [why Sun deprecated Thread.stop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html)

Comment: @user3151902: there's no guarantee that interrupting the thread will do anything, and this will only work if the code in question has been wired to respond to an interrupt, no?

Comment: No, there is no guarantee. Unfortunately, there is also no guarantee the thread will respond to stop(). See the linked Sun article for more details.

Comment: @user3151902 OP's question is not about using `stop()` or `interrupt()` instead he wants to know how to clean up the particular thread.`stop()` will also work however not recommended!!!

Comment: @user3151902: Oh, I agree completely that `.stop()` should *never* be used. The key to solving this problem is to gain a full understanding of the 3rd party library, to see if it has been wired to allow stopping, and if not, the OP is out of luck. There is no answer to be found here on this site, only within the 3rd party library documentation and source code itself.

Comment: I should have mentioned in my original post, interrupting the JDBC access thread does not have any effect. I'll edit the post.

Comment: I would try to access the database network connection via reflection and close it. Usually this should bring back the thread "to life" as long as it does not wait for something internally or has some other sort of deadlock.

Comment: @Mandy8055: what do you mean by "will have the same consequences..." since as far as I understand things, this is patently untrue. One is exceedingly dangerous to call, the other is safe, but may or may not work -- both entirely different consequences in my eye.

Comment: OP, do you use a connection pool?

Comment: re:Connection pool; Not currently, but I could. Currently, if the thread hangs, I open a new connection and retry.

Comment: Robert: I suppose I could try that, but I imagine that the socket variable is buried pretty deep. That's a better alternative than anything else I can think of though.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the Thread repeated interruption should kill it. If that doesn't work, there is a major bug in the JDBC driver, in which case a stop call could be a (bad) solution.

The problem with stop is that potentially resources are not cleaned up properly (like TCP/IP connections) and could linger in the background, till eventually your system becomes clogged up and fails completely.

I would try to enforce interruption to see if that has any effect, like interrupting 1000 times in a row. If that has no effect, then you don't have any other option but calling stop, in which case you probably also need daily or hourly restarts.

An alternate, but also much more complex solution, could be to have an additional process that is a simple proxy to the database, which can then be safely restarted without affecting the main system too much.

Answer (score -3):

we should never use Thread.stop() , It may leave threads to unmanageable state.
That's why this method got depricated by Sun.

best way to use interrupt() method , inside thread run  method we can check isInterrupted() which will tell if thread is interrupted or not.  if its interrupted perform some task if you want any  and come out of run method , in this way thread's life will get ended in cleaner way.

Comment: As explained in comments above, this answer will simply not work.

Comment: above statements is perfectly correct , this  approach should be used by whoever writing threads, in this case if vendor would have  implemented his threads like aforementioned approach then there would not be any problem.

Comment: Fine. But it does not answer the original poster's question. My down-vote stays.